# Mysql, select rows according to date

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysqli

The thing I would like to do:

Select the row where date = 2012-10-14 and then display 4 rows which go after that row. So from this list

```
2012-10-12 column #2
2012-10-13 column #2
2012-10-14 was very sunny.
2012-10-15 rained all day.
2012-10-16 whatever.
2012-10-17 column #2
2012-10-18 column #2
2012-10-19 rained all day.
2012-10-20 whatever.
2012-10-21 column #2
2012-10-22 column #2
```

it would return this:

```
2012-10-14 was very sunny.
2012-10-15 rained all day.
2012-10-16 whatever.
2012-10-17 column #2
2012-10-18 column #2
```

Thanks for help.

PS: In the database there are no data on weekends so some of the dates will be missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date >= '2012-10-14' ORDER BY date LIMIT 5
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba997/1/0).

Answer (score 1):

This version is for a date range rather than for a fixed number of rows. It is not completely clear which one you want.

```
select * from mytable where date_diff(date,'2012-10-14') <= 4 and date >= '2012-10-14';
```

Comment: In this case, I'd be tempted to do something a little more explicit: `WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-10-14' AND '2012-10-14' + INTERVAL 4 DAY`.